# HTML and Javascript Automated Document Erases Entries After OnClick Event

Tags: javascript, html, postback, notepad, buttonclick

I am automating a document with HTML and JavaScript through MS Notepad.  So far, I have lots of text, a few textboxes, and a button, which will execute a JavaScript function after a number is entered into one of the textboxes.  This document is only partially completed; however, I noticed that after I add entries into my textboxes and then press the button, all of my entries erase.  I believe this is a postback issue of some sort; however, I thought using an `onlick` event with JavaScript would not execute a server-side command.  Also, my document is all client-side code.  Basically, it is just text, HTML, and, currently, one JS function.

As a reiteration, would anyone know why my textbox entries erase after a button's `onclick` event executes, and how to stop this from happening?  Additionally, the `onclick` event executes the JS function, which is an if statement that adds more text to the document.

Thank you,

DFM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have an `<input type="submit">` button in your form then when you press the button the form will get submitted, even if you have an `onclick` handler. There are several ways to solve this*, but the easiest way is to change the button to `type="button"`, which is identical except clicking it does not submit anything.

```
<input type="button" onclick="checkEntries()" />
```

*Other solutions include adding `return false` to your `onclick` handler, as in `onclick="checkEntries(); return false"`, or adding `onsubmit="return false"` to the `<form>` element.

Comment: Wow - I actually responded above with a question that you answered before I pressed "add comment".  You must have been reading my mind or seen this sophomoric problem many times before.  Nonetheless, thank you for your reply.  I will try this tomorrow.

Comment: I also have your bank account numbers now.